# Show current date time from CRM in the front end?

Tags: c#, date, time, dynamics-crm, crm

I have the logic below the Answer Value in CRM is 01/08/2015 23:00:00, however in the front end changes the expiry date to show 02/08/2015, its adding 1 day not sure why, how would I show the same date from CRM? below is my code, do I have to do below to show UTC now or something?

```
List<Answer> answers = Queries.FormAnswersQueries.GetAnswers(correctFormAnswer.Id).FetchEntities<Answer>(connection.OrganizationService);

if (answers != null)
{
    answers = answers
        .GroupBy(c => c.Question.Id)
        .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(c => c.CreatedOn).First()).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a time zone problem. Are the times in your DB stored in UTC or local time? If you go into your debugger and check your answers list about the details of your CreatedOn property you should see what kind of date time is assumed. Then check in your CRM what kind of date time it assumes there and fix it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", CreatedOn);
```

Do this to know you're sending the correct format, it looks like you might be rounding off to the next day. Check all your conversions on the front-end and round down if need be and use a debugger to check each value of 'CreatedOn' being sent.

Comment: Where can i add this in the code is it something like  .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(c => String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", CreatedOn()).First()).ToList(); however this says CreatedOn does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamics CRM stores all datetime fields in UTC format in database. When retrieve this will come as it is & you have to convert to required local timezone.

Use `LocalTimeFromUtcTimeRequest` to manipulate the datetime.

> The SDK Web Services can accept either a local datetime or a UTC datetime when performing a create/update, but will always return a UTC date on Retrieve/RetrieveMultiple.

[Read more](http://develop1.net/public/post/Dynamics-CRM-DateTimes-the-last-word.aspx)